# Django, avoid foreingkey check on the modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

How i could avoid the foreingkey check on the modelform when save a record, because this make 2 additional queries, and i need speed on the application.

```
SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model, use the [`db_index`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index) option.

```
 field = django.db.models.ForeignKey('Field', db_index=False)
```

Django documentation for [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey. You can disable this by setting db_index to False. You may want to avoid the overhead of an index if you are creating a foreign key for consistency rather than joins, or if you will be creating an alternative index like a partial or multiple column index.

EDIT: `db_index=False` will turn off the *database* foreign key check on `INSERT` or `UPDATE`,  but it will not affect Django's form validation, which happens *before* an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

You have four options. The first is the easiest.

(1) Don't validate the form. Create it with

```
form = MyForm(initial=request.GET.items())
```

and then don't call `is_valid()`.

(2) Override the form's `is_valid` method. This allows you to still validate some fields (but not the others) by calling `validate()` on them.

(3) Create your own form field type, without validators.

(4) Don't use a Django form. Create your own form HTML, validation, and model save.

Comment: I tried your example, but this doesn't work. I'm using postgreSQL, Django 1.6c1 and Python 2.7.4

Comment: Are these queries run anytime the record is saved?

Comment: Yes, when i call the save method on the modelform "myModelForm.save()"

Comment: I cannot find the answer, I don't  know if these 2 queries are mandatory on django.

Comment: The same queries appear when I execute is_valid() on the modelform.

Comment: That's all I needed, I cannot use the modelform because execute extra queries, but I think is good idea put this functionality on the framework, in some situations the speed is mandatory, and You have not time to validate if the fereingkey exist or not.

Thank you.